# jquery show and hide and the checkbox state

Tags: jquery, cordova

Situation:

I have a UL that lists a bunch of people
I have two buttons on top  "All" and "Common"

On load you see all of the people. You can then click the Common button and the UL is filtered to only certain people.

This works fine. But in each LI I have 2 checkboxes - when I check them in the All category and then select the Recent tab to check other people and then I go back to the All tab I sometimes lose the checkbox state.

It should be noted that this is being developed with phonegap

```
function getFriends(common)
{

if(common=="common")
{  
   //Hide everyone to start with
   $("#PersonSelection li").hide();
   //ajax query that loops through the common players goes here
   $('#'+item.PlayerId).show(); //this is the id of each li that is common, so after I hide all I   just show those that are common
   //end ajax loop
} else {
  if ($("#PersonSelection li").size() > 1) //this is there for when we go from common back to all I don't have to go back to the DB
  {
   $("#PersonSelection li").show();
  }
  else
    {
    //go back to ajax query that loops a variable with li and checkbox info and the appends
    document.getElementById('PersonSelection').innerHTML += people;
    }
}
```

Comment: In order for you to get a more helpful answer, you should provide a sample of your html and javascript together. possibly through jsfiddle.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the value of `people`. It doesn't include the updates to checkbox state. Why doesn't the `All` button just show all the `LI`s insteaad of rebuilding the whole list?

Comment: Your question is also confusing. At the beginning you mention `All` versus `Common`, but the problem description refers to `All` versus `Recent`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out - I thought I had debugged pretty good, but it was and issue with this document.getElementById('PersonSelection').innerHTML += people;